# Test cases in TestNG are not executed by maven

Tags: maven, selenium

I have the maven project with testng script as below:

```
package TestMaven;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class mavenTestDemo {

@Test
public void add() {
    System.out.println("Addintion");
    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    assertEquals(30, a+b);
}

@Test
public void sub() {
    System.out.println("Subtraction");
    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    assertEquals(10, b-a);
}

@Test
public void mult() {
    System.out.println("Multiplication");
    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    assertEquals(200, a*b);
}


}
```

Pom.xml as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MavenDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MavenDemo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

 </properties>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

when i excute the code through maven i get following output:
I directly executed from eclipse using "maven test" option and also tried from command line with the command "mvn clean install"
For both the execution i am getting below result--->

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< MavenDemo:MavenDemo >-------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MavenDemo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Shilpa Khandge\eclipse-workspace\MavenDemo\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MavenDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavenDemo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Shilpa Khandge\eclipse-workspace\MavenDemo\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavenDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ MavenDemo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.900 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-09T14:33:56+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Testng.xml and define the test class and run rerun the tests via mvn clean install. 
make sure you define the testng.xml in pom.xml  surefire plugin. so that maven invokes your testng.xml and then in turn that points to test methods.

Answer (score 0):

Please add maven surefire plugin in your pom.xml which shall be pointing to **testng.xml**

```
<plugins>

 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

</plugins>
```

Then run `mvn install`

Comment: Problem is solved now. Thank you all for your inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

For TestNg to recognise the @Test methods the class name should end with Test.

In your case rename the class name from mavenTestDemo to **MavenTest** or any other name ending with Test.

Or else you need to have a testng.xml file having the test classes included.